# jquery UI dialog buttons - return true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, callback, confirm

```
buttons     : {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return (typeof callback == 'string') ?
                  window.location.href = callback :
                  callback();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        },
```

For jquery UI, I need to return values the same as a javascript confirm message a 1 and a 0

I assume I do a callback, but unsure how to reference the callback...

***EDIT***

jsp developer stated that he doesn't neccessarily need a callback, but needs to be able to do something similar to:

```
if (answer == true) { 
        //do something 
} 
else { 
        //do something different 
}
```

how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a return in a jquery dialog.

What you can do:

```
buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback_fn(1);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback_fn(0);
        }
    },


//later on:
function callback_fn(bool){
    //do something with the 1 or 0
}
```